# How to cancel download inside DownloadHandler with Cefsharp

Tags: cefsharp

Open a pdf file, click the download button, the download will start because I implemented an IDownloadHandler interface as source code suggested (callback.Continue).

I want to replace the download process with my own, I just want to know when the click button is clicked, so I write below code in OnBeforeDownload:

```
    downloadItem.IsCancelled = true;
    if (!callback.IsDisposed)
    {
        using (callback)
        {
            callback.Dispose();
            //callback.Continue(downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, showDialog: true);
        }
    }
```

But OnDownloadUpdated function still be called periodically, does that mean the download process is still on, how to cancel the download process? thanks!

Note: I use Cefsharp.Winforms, the version is 81.3.100.0, my os is Windows 10, visual studio 2019.

```
===========================================
public class PDFDownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnBeforeDownloadFired;

    public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnDownloadUpdatedFired;

    private IDownloadItemCallback downloadCallback = null;

    public void OnBeforeDownload(IWebBrowser webBrowser, IBrowser browser, 
DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
{
if (this.downloadCallback != null)
{
    this.downloadCallback.Cancel();
}

// this is my own download dialog blabla, not call Continue here.
}
        public void OnDownloadUpdated(IWebBrowser webBrowser, IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
        {
            this.downloadCallback = callback;
            OnDownloadUpdatedFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);
        }
}
```

first OnDownloadUpdated is called, then OnBeforeDownload is called, then several other OnDownloadUpdated ....

Comment: Yoi can keep a reference to IDownloadItemCallback and call http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_IDownloadItemCallback_Cancel.htm

Comment: I get a reference in OnDownloadUpdated and call Cancel() in OnBeforeDownload, but still OnDownloadUpdated is called periodically.

Comment: Please show your code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: update the post, please have a check.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed example, your code is incomplete,  the download shouldn't even start with the code you've posted.

Comment: that is what I wanted, cancel the download, However, with my updated code, the OnDownloadUpdated still be called periodically.

Comment: Updated code again.

Comment: Please show the entire class that implements IDownloadHandler where are you calling http://cefsharp.github.io/api/83.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBeforeDownloadCallback_Continue.htm you cannot access IDownloadItemCallback in OnBeforeDownload as it's called first.

Comment: Just updated, Please note OnBeforeDownload is not called first.

Comment: OnBeforeDownload should be  called first,  if for some reason it's not then this is a bug in the Chromium embedded framework. Please fork https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and provide an example that reproduces the problem. Squash your changes into a single commit and push your changes to GitHub. Please make sure the changes are just the minimum required to reproduce this problem. This is an important debugging step.

Comment: My understanding of the behaviour appears to be incorrect,   https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17803#p46546 has clarification on expected behaviour.